# Should I override Enum.toString() to localize an enum's label?

Tags: java, jsf, localization

Today, I have a style question: Given the following code, should I be overriding `Enum#toString()` to present the application user a localized string or switch to a custom function (say, `getLabel()`) or is there another method to achieve the same effect?

I'm mainly after staying DRY here, so hardcoding the resource bundle prefix is not an option.

I have a simple enum like this:

```
public enum DUE_DATE {
   START,
   PRESENTED;

   public String toString() {
       return DBResBundle.instance().getString("due_date_lbl_" + name());
   }
}
```

where `DBResBundle` is my ResourceBundle implementation that I can access as `msg` in JSF like so:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{m.due_date}" id="due">
  <f:selectItems value="#{dueDates}" var="d" 
    itemLabel="#{msg['due_date_lbl_'.concat(d.name())]}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I'm also using the the enum in code (not just JSF) context, but I don't utilize the `toString()` there.

Comment: Where would `toString()` find the locale used to retrieve the appropriate localized message?

Comment: I would go for the `getLabel()`, because it can represent its semantics better in this case. The semantics of `toString()` isn't really defined and most of its use is for debugging.

Comment: @JBNizet it's currently fetching the locale from JSF's viewRoot. Which is admittedly bad design and will get a fallback to the currently logged in user's stored locale I have available elsewhere.

Comment: @HannoBinder yeah, the concern that prompted the question was that the  JavaDoc for `Enum#toString()` says it's output should be programmer-readable, not end user readable.

Comment: Right. And that's why people would expect `toString()` to be just like that. Thus, good style will be *not* to use `toString()` for the UI or anything like that.

Comment: Besides, having the code of a functional enum tight to a particular view technology and singletons or threadlocals containing the locale is also a problem. Your object model shouldn't care about the view layer.

Comment: Agree with the layer separation argument, which also rules out `getLabel()`. So maybe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15633007/785663 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with a method `getMsgKey()` on all of my enums that basically does

```
return getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + name();
```

Which is just like [Internationalization of multiple enums (translation of enum values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633007/internationalization-of-multiple-enums-translation-of-enum-values) but without the `EnumTranslator`.