# JSF showing conditional text in a clear way

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, enums, resourcebundle

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{Account.Status eq 'FAILED' }">
            <h:outputText value="# {msg['account/failed']}" escape="false" />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{Account.Status eq 'SUCCESS' }">
            <h:outputText value="# {msg['account/success']}" escape="false" />
</h:panelGroup>

...more panelgroup messages like this for all different Status types,
 and different messages to be shown..
```

On my glassfish Jee6 application, I show my messages depending of the status of the account, I keep my strings in a text file and reach from JSF page as above {msg['account/failed']}

Now these if-else Status conditions are getting more for different types of messages, and make the JSF page a mess, how can I do the same thing from the Java code?

I can set the value of the message and put the if else condition in my Java code but then how I will access to my text file where I keep my strings? or any other clean JSF way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the account status is an enum, I'd publish the method

```
public static String toString(Enum<?> e) {
    ResourceBundle bundle = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getResourceBundle("messages");
    return bundle.getString(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + "/" + e.name());
}
```

as [EL-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function), and use it like

```
#{e:toString(Account.status)}
```

(code untested as I don't have an eclipse at hand, but the general idea ought to be sound)

Comment: tnx looks like this can help me, but since my JSF knowledge is very little I dont know how I can use this idea. This is for how to access external txt file only I guess? maybe you could edit question to explain a  bit more how this looks in xhtml and java file?

Comment: and why use a el-function instead of calling that method like a normal method like #{bean.toString(Account.status)} ?

Comment: For brevity and readability of the el expression. Sure, you could write #{enumFormatter.toString(Account.status)}, but that's somewhat lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

Just make the enum value part of bundle key. E.g.

```html
<c:set var="key" value="account.status.#{account.status}" />
<h:outputText value="#{msg[key]}" escape="false" />
```

*(I only replaced `/` by `.` and lowercased the instance/property names conform standard conventions)*

with

```
account.status.FAILED = Failed
account.status.SUCCESS = Success
```

Alternatively, make the key a property of the enum. See also among others:

- [How to use enum values in f:selectItem(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-make-a-dropdown-menu-of-a-enum-in-jsf/8229982#8229982)
- [Localizing enum values in resource bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375578/jsf-best-way-to-enum-internationalization-i18n).

Comment: +1: What a nice way to work around the absence of a string concatentation operator in el.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to use JSTL tags ...I worked with JSF and sometimes you have to try a few things. 
you can use  ,

```
   <c:if test="condition">
   <h:outputText value="# {msg['account/success']}" escape="false" />
  </c:if>
```

or use

```
    <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${param.enter=='1'}">
  <h:outputText value="# {msg['account/success']}" escape="false" />
          </c:when>

          <c:otherwise>
         <h:outputText value="# {msg['account/failed']}" escape="false" />
          </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Comment: JSTL tags and JSF are a big no no! This can cause major headaches when mixed with facelets!

Comment: I respectfully disagree with you. There are circumstances that you may want to use JSTL with JSF given what you want to accomplish.

Comment: That may be so, but is this such a case? Not knowing whether the account status changes during the lifecycle of the view, the advice to use JSTL rather than the rendered attribute can be quite hazardous - and I don't see any compelling advantage JSTL can offer here?

Comment: @meriton I think your solution is definitely the best approach here but I just wanted to mention that too just in case to give him/her another option.

Comment: @user717630 JSTL should only be used to cut a component tree out of the view completely. There are a few cases where this may be a valid use, but the above is not one of them. If he has any sort of `f:ajax` in his view, JSTL will cause various problems. `<ui:fragment>` would be much more appropriate here.